# Archiving large number of files with TAR

Tags: tar, hp-ux

Trying to clean up a directory on an HP/UX system that has a stupid number of files. I've already tried:

Create an archive of all files older than "x" days. (This method, using the find command, even when selecting only 5 days worth of files, ran "forever".)

So now I'm trying to just do one day at a time using a filemask:

```
tar -czf SV*20150227*.evt SV_EVT_FILES_ARCHIVE_20150227.tar'
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error like this:

```
tar: SV_EVT_FILES_ARCHIVE_20150227.tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

I followed the tutorial at: `http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-tar-command-examples/` but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Can anyone shed some light on where I screwed up?

Thanks

Comment: try with tar -czf SV_EVT_FILES_ARCHIVE_20150227.tar SV*20150227*.evt

Answer (score 2):

This is the rigth command to compress your file :

```
  tar -cvzf {Archive.tar.gz} {TargetFolder}
```

you did the opposite ;)

if you dont want to zip it, remove z param:

```
  tar -cvf {Archive.tar} {TargetFolder}
```